# Xamarin Forms Element Parent property is null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a `ViewCell` that is used as an item template for a `ListView`:

```
ListView details_list = new ListView ();
details_list.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CartViewCell));
```

Inside the ViewCell I would like to have a function to access the ListView's itemSource in order to delete an item. I though I would do this by accessing the `Parent` property inside the `ViewCell`

```
ListView parent = (ListView)this.Parent;
```

But when I attempt this, it shows the parent to be null. Is this an incorrect way to be using the `Parent` property? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried  view.ParentForAccessibility ?

Comment: In general, you should not edit ListView.ItemsSource from UI. You'd better have the ObservableCollection<> of items in your ViewModel together with a Command to operate on it.

Comment: So my ViewModel has an ObservableCollection<> in it. How can I access the viewmodel from inside the ViewCell? I want to use a MenuItem with a command, but I don't know how to access the ViewModel from that command.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it does not work in Xamarin.Forms (in Xamarin.Android works), sorry.

Answer (score 4):

there is an override method you have to call it then the parent will not be null

```
protected override void OnParentSet()
        {
            object view = Parent;
            base.OnParentSet();

            if (view.GetType() == typeof(Grid))
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this; two possibilities include

1. Use a Command

Define a Command in your ViewModel,

```
// define a command property
public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

// in your constructor, initialize the command
DeleteCommand = new Command<string>((id) =>
{
  // do the appropriate delete action here
}
```

and then in your ViewCell bind to it

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID}" Text="Delete" />
```

2. Use message passing

In your ViewModel, subscribe to a message:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyViewCell, string> (this, "Delete", (sender, id) => {
    // do the appropriate delete action here
});
```

In your ViewCell, send the message whenever they click the button (or whatever triggers the action) - ID should be and identifier for the particular item

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MyViewCell, string> (this, "Delete", ID);
```

Comment: But the ````bindingcontext```` of each ````ViewCell```` is an object in an ````observeablecollection<>```` in my viewmodel. How can I bind the ````ViewCell```` to the actual viewmodel?

Comment: Ah, good point.  You could either define the command on each item in the collection, and have it call a method in the parent VM; but it might be easier to try the Messaging approach